# Creating shapefile layer from points added using Go To XY tool of ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, point, xy

How do you create a shapefile from points created using the Go To XY tool?

Comment: If you want to manually do this create a new shapefile and digitize the points. Before you clicke to add a point right click into the map. There you have the option to add the exact coordinates for the point to be set.

Comment: Possible yes, but I think you would be ill advised to use that workflow. I think it would be far more sensible to create a new feature class and pay close attention to using the Define Projection tool to get its coordinate system right.

Comment: Perhaps you are reversing Latitude and Longitude of your Table columns.

Comment: It sounds like you're assigning the coordinate system of your other layers or of the data frame. Make sure you're assigning a geographic coordinate system to the xy layer.

Comment: I think you should use the advice provided so far and if you are still stuck then [edit] your question to provide precise details of each step you perform paying particular attention to any coordinate system decisions you are making.

Comment: @PolyGeo - not sure how my question could be considered unclear, I was just providing background information on why I was reduced to using the Go To XY tool. The coordinate systems were right (as specified by my question before editing.) Nevertheless, Ive updated the question to its most basic form, how do you create a shapefile using points created by the Go to XY tool.

Comment: If you have a lot of points to create, I would suggest putting all of the coordinates in a table or csv format.  Then use Add XY Data to create a temporary spatial layer. From there, you can export the temporary layer to create a permanent one.  You can also select the geographic or projected coordinate system to match as you export. Judging by other comments, I've probably missed some of the conversation though.

Comment: If you have non-decimal degree coordinates, you can put those in a csv or text file as well and use the Convert Coordinate Notation tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plot your X,Y points with the "Go To XY" tool, as you've stated. For each X,Y that you plot, use the "Add Point" button so that ArcMap drops a graphic "point" at each location you're interested in. When you have them all plotted and you're ready to convert them to a shapefile, go to the "Drawing" toolbar's drop-down menu and choose "Convert Graphics to Features".

As others have stated, this isn't the most efficient way to create a featureclass out of X,Y coordinates, but if it's the process/workflow that works best for you, so be it! Good luck!

Comment: Perfect thank you! Id upvote but I dont have enough reputation yet.